# Trying to upload a file and display a GoogleVisTable with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I'm totally new to shiny and googlevis. in my IU.R, I have a button to upload a csv and a few other options captured as header sep and quote. My server.R looks like this

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive ({
  inFile <- input$file1
  df<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
      })
  gvisTable(data()$df)

})
```

but it doesn't work at all. 'file' datapath is empty. just trying to upload a file and display a GoogleVisTable. I used reactive because I had an Environment error otherwise.

Comment: You are not returning a list with element `df` from `data()`. You are just returning `df` itself so `data()` rather then `data()$df` should suffice.